# How long does it take to consume the same amount of food

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

For a group of 32 students food lasts for 45 days. For how many days will the same food last for 72 students?

Comment: Are you considering a proportional case?

Comment: yes, I think so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
32 students ~ 1/45 days
72 students  ~ 1/x days
x=32*45/72 = 20
```

[Inverse proportionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_proportionality)

Comment: you rock, thanks

Comment: @Joe:you're welcome ;)  A cartoon explanation can be found here :http://www.emathematics.net/porcentajes1.php?tp=3

Comment: The answer is correct, but the reasoning seems peculiar: Why is it $x$ students, when the question is asking for the number of days?

Comment: @dbaupp fixed it.thanks ;)

Answer (score 11):

Think of a student as needing (precisely) one kg of noodles a day. Since the noodles will last $45$ students for $32$ days, we must have $(32)(45)$ kg of noodles. This will last $72$ students a total of $\frac{(32)(45)}{72}$ days. Calculate.

There are many other approaches, some more algebraic than others. *Whatever* approach you take, note that it is obvious that (under the assumption that food need for each student is fixed) the food will last $72$ students **fewer** than $32$ days. So after you do a calculation, do an informal reality check: if your "answer" is greater than $32$, it *must* be wrong.

Comment: It is not obvious that the food will last 72 students fewer than 32 days.  Assume the first group of students were big college student-athletes and the second group of students were meek little kindergartners.  Without making assumptions this question can not be answered.

Comment: @emory: Thanks. the assumption had already mentioned in the first paragraph ($1$ kg of noodles). But it is a good idea to keep stressing underlying assumptions, so now it is also mentioned in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

total students are $32$ and food last for $45$ days. Total quantity of food is $32\cdot 45$

Same food to be distributed to $72$ studentss (assuming rate is equal)

Therefore total food will last for 72 students for $\frac{32\cdot 45}{72}= 20$ days.